# Dealing with not conventioned table names in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE CS_GRPUSU (
    GRPUSU  NUMERIC(3,0) NOT NULL,
    DESGRP  VARCHAR(20)
);
ALTER TABLE CS_GRPUSU ADD PRIMARY KEY (GRPUSU);
```

How should be constructed my controller and model (file names and basic content)? Could someone give me examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model class should be defined like:

model:

```
class Example extends AppModel {
     public $useTable = 'CS_GRPUSU'; // This model uses table 'CS_GRPUSU'
     public $primaryKey = 'GRPUSU'; //for cakephp 1.3 use 'var' instead of 'public'
}
```

controller:

```
class Test exptends AppController{
    public $uses = array('Example');

    public function add(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

if you are using cakephp 1.3 then please replace public keyword with var

like

```
var $uses = array('Example');//cakephp 1.3
public $uses = array('Example'); //cakephp 2 and above
```

Comment: What about the name of the model file, and the name and content of controller file? thanks!

Comment: you can put your desired name and in controller you can create controller with any name and if want to use that model as default model you can put "var $uses = array('MODEL_NAME');" in controller

Comment: Ok, got it... I thought I would must adapt the name of my table for the file names. Thanks